# IKVM Does not found Provider if run with process.start while using pdfbox.net

Tags: c#, pdfbox, ikvm

im ins strugle with a strange Problem.
i have written an dll (as addin for Navision) which calls  an console application throu process.start(). The console application using IKVM to use pdfbox.net (v1.8.4).

if i run the console application directly (using cmd or "start" in visual studio) everything works fine.
If i start the console app throu process.start() from the class libary (tested with unit test (mstest)) or any other (test-) project i get an exception:

> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not
>   found

My process.start from the class lib:

```
string[] args = {pdfFilePath, zugferdFilePath};
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = exeFile,
    Arguments = string.Join(" ", args),
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    ErrorDialog = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Details about the exception:
Message:

> Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found

Source:

> IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API

StackTrace:

> ((java.lang.Throwable)_exception).StackTrace "   bei javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
>   bei Mustang.ZUGFeRDImporter.parse() in C:\GIT\KCorp.NAV.Zugferd\KCorp.Nav.Zugferd.Split\Mustang\ZUGFeRDImport.cs:Zeile 124.
>   bei KCorp.Nav.Zugferd.Split.Zaumzeug.showZUGFeRD(String filepath,String xmlFilePath) in C:\GIT\KCorp.NAV.Zugferd\KCorp.Nav.Zugferd.Split\Zaumzeug.cs:Zeile 30."

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

If you need further information please let me know.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classloader problem. Try adding the following before the line you call the factory:

```
var s = new  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.@internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl();
```

This will force the assembly to load and has worked for me every time I've encountered this problem.